# Joomla 3 and Simple Image Gallery - doesn't parse {gallery}

Tags: parsing, joomla, tags, gallery, joomla-extensions

I have a problem to make Simple Image Gallery to work in Joomla 3. It doesn't display any pictures, actually it doesn't even care about them.

I have this pages:
http://utsnorthsath.kangoowebs.com/gallery/images/34-short-course-cross-country

It looks like {gallery} tag is not recognized/parse and no gallery is displayed. Does this module SIG require any additional action after installing to tell Joomla that {gallery} tag should be parsed now?

I don't get any error message, just the content is not parsed.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just as BodgeIT I'd say that probably the plugin is not enabled (Check Extensions > Plugins > Simple Image Gallery). This is the default state for newly installed plugins in Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want to teach you to suck eggs but when I find {plugincodes} rendered as is, it either means you haven't used the syntax correctly or you haven't enabled the plugin in Plugin Manager.

One other thing which may be affecting the plugin is that you load jquery before Mootools.

Best practice is to load these the other way around.

You could look for an excellent plugin called JQuery Easy which should fix that issue and possibly the Gallery issue too, if the above isn't it.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much! I thought that I need to enable only "modules" and I did. However, I didn't think about enabling it in "plugins". Once I did it started to work. 

I still have problem with Slimbox/Lightbox (it looks like nothing works), but the tag {gallery} started to be parsed now.